# Reporting mode for Android sensor with API less than 21

Tags: android, android-sensors

Hardware sensors on Android describe the mode in which they report data through [`Sensor.getReportingMode()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#getReportingMode()), but this method is only available on API level 21 or greater.  So I'm wondering what's the reporting mode one should expect for sensors when API level is less than 21.

This information is useful because knowing the reporting mode of a sensor helps you determine if the `samplingPeriodUs` argument to `SensorManager.registerListener()` is likely to be an upper bound on the number of nanoseconds between reported sensor events (this might not be true for a sensor with a reporting mode of `REPORTING_MODE_ON_CHANGE` but might be true of a sensor with a reporting mode of `REPORTING_MODE_CONTINUOUS`....real life testing shows these assumptions aren't that sound though).

And knowing whether or not the sensor has a reporting mode of `REPORTING_MODE_ONE_SHOT` determines whether one should subscribe to sensor events coming from this sensor with `SensorManager.registerListener()`
(from method docs: "Note: Don't use this method with one-shot trigger sensors...Use `getReportingMode()` to obtain the reporting mode of a given sensor.") or with `SensorManager.requestTriggerSensor()`.

To put my question another way, to know if you should register for sensor events by using either

```
SensorManager.registerListener() // don't use with mode REPORTING_MODE_ONE_SHOT
```

which was added in API 3, or

```
SensorManager.requestTriggerSensor() // only for mode REPORTING_MODE_ONE_SHOT
```

which was added in API 18, you need to use

```
Sensor.getReportingMode()
```

which wasn't added until API 21.

Am I missing something, and if not how do I get around this?

Comment: You basically just figure out the type of sensor it is from the data returned and program in the right one.  Since the only use case of grabbing a random sensor and writing the data I can think of is the case of an example app that just dumps all sensors, there really isn't a need for a programtic way of telling what one to use.

Comment: @GabeSechan: I'm not sure if I understand.  You're saying that to determine if I should use `SensorManager.registerListener()` or `SensorManager.requestTriggerSensor()` to register for sensor events, with API less than 21, I would look at the data returned by the sensor (through a registered listener)?  Or are you speaking more to the part of differentiating between `REPORTING_MODE_ON_CHANGE` and `REPORTING_MODE_CONTINUOUS` by looking at the reported data (which makes sense to me, but an answer found that way wouldn't work generally across all models, since the sensor behavior could change)?